# CORS in Ionic and third party api(Smartsheet)

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

I am trying to get data from smartsheet API. When I use postman and nodejs in separate server code, it works.

But if I use the API inside the Ionic with HttpClient (@angular/http) it gives CORS issue with run in browser.

```
Failed to load https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/1235941564208899972: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

And also I have tried with a proxy setup like below:

```
  "proxies": [{
    "path": "/2.0",
    "proxyUrl": "https://api.smartsheet.com/"
  }]
```

home.ts:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.HttpClient.get('/2.0/sheets/1235941564208899972', options).pipe(
    map(res => res.json())
).subscribe(data => this.response = data);
```

I am still getting localhost 404 error only.

Comment: You can use cors chrome extension for this

Comment: if i use cors extension it will work in that particular browser, when take the build it will not work @PareshGami

Comment: When you make build and running in real device no cors errors coming

Comment: If i understand correctly, there don't have cros issue when after getting build app. may i right. @PareshGami,..

Comment: yes you understand correctly

Comment: ok, i will check and update you shortly @PareshGami

Comment: sure let me know if anything

Comment: its work,.. finally CROS issue solved. thanks @PareshGami

Comment: @Kitta you'll want to revoke the access token that you posted in this question, and create a new one. As of right now anyone who sees this post can can access to your Smartsheet data. I'll edit the question so that the access token is no longer visible, but you'll still want to revoke it in Smartsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If Ionic is using CORS to talk to the Smartsheet API, that will not work. The Smartsheet API does not currently support CORS.

Comment: You would interact with the Smartsheet API through a server-side technology such as Node.

Comment: yes, done with separate server side code. but i have trying to fix without server side, only use api http client request to fix,.. this will sense to code reduce as my assumption..(In first line of query i have mentioned early about serverside)